# Why can't I view a .jpg texture in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

I am learning three.js and I am unable to map a jpg image that is the correct dimensions (power of two)
I am loading it into a lambert material but i have had issues viewing imported textures with every material i have tried.
Double checked the filename and it seems to be correct.
I am using Five Server to serve and preview the project locally

I tried to change the type of material and it still isn't displaying the image.
I am expecting the image to map to the object I am loading it into but it will not.
Tried asking GPT as well and none of its suggestions are displaying the imported texture. Currently running the project on manjaro linux in chromium.

```
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

//const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

//const gradientMap = loader.load( 'fiveTone.jpg');

gsap.to(".txt", {duration: 2, x:425});

const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 3, 2, 2);
const geometry2 = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 1, 32, 32);
const floorgeo = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 20, 20);

//const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x6AA84F } );

const material2 = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
  color: 0x3e32a8,
  emissive: 0x3e32a8,
  side: THREE.DoubleSide,
  map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load('trianglefabric.jpg')

});

const material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
    color: 0xafc9b6,
    emissive: 0xafc9b6,
    map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load('trianglefabric.jpg'),
  });

const wireframe = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 0xff0000, 
    transparent: true,
    opacity: 0.5,
    wireframe: true,
    wireframeLinewidth: 3,
  });

const floor = new THREE.Mesh(floorgeo, material2);
const cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
const sphere = new THREE.Mesh( geometry2, wireframe );
scene.add( floor );
scene.add( cube );
scene.add( sphere );

sphere.position.set( 2, 0, 0 );
floor.position.set( 0, -2, 0 );
floor.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2;

camera.position.z = 5;

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
    cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
    sphere.rotation.y += -0.01;

    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}

animate();
```

Comment: Your scene doesn’t have any lights in it.

Comment: If adding lights to your scene does not solve the issue, please use this fiddle to demonstrate the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/eacnuqyg/